# Selecting a curve by its name with a Python script

Tags: python, scripting, objects, fcurves

Is it possible with a Python script to select the curve of an object with its name ("location x", "location y", "rotation z", ....) instead of its number.

For example, I tweak the Z location of an object with

```
bpy.data.objects["Pixel X0006 Y0006"].animation_data.action.fcurves[2].keyframe_points[0].interpolation = 'LINEAR'
```

and I would like to select it by a name rather than with `fcurves[2]`. It would be more convenient for my scripts.

**Is it possible to do that ?**

Comment: Try printing the name of the curve.  Try to [find] the curve by name.  I will check to see where this function is.  You may be faster than I am.

Answer (score -2):

Yes its possible.

This is an excerpt from an older, non latest version of Blender script.  The relevant part may still work. Note the find function.  You can see the name of the curve in the FCurves Editor Panel.  Note curves may have an index X in the set [0,1,2].

```
object_bq = bpy.data.objects[name]
test = object_bq.animation_data.action if (None != object_bq.animation_data and (None != object_bq.animation_data.action)) else None;
if (test):
    fc = object_bq.animation_data.action.fcurves.find("Some Curve Name Visible in the FCurves Editor Panel");
```

fcurves.find

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html?highlight=fcurves%20find#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.find